# XPath string for selecting data types

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectsinglenode

I have an XML Document that specifies certain data instead data nodes like so:

```
<data type= "arbitrary value">Value</data>
```

I need to be able to look through this document and select the above node.

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(data[contains(.,'arbitrary value')]);
```

The above statement does not work.

How can I find nodes with a certain "type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath `data[@type='arbitrary value']` will select all "data" nodes with a type attribute containing the text "arbitrary value"

So:

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("data[@type='arbitrary value']")
```